# What's the difference between "net user" and add a user through Control Panel?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I run a Windows 2008 server, and when I do `net user XXX strong_password /ad` I got a command succeed message, but unable to log on with that user and password, it kept telling me password or username is wrong.

But if I do the same through `Control Panel->User And Accounts`, the user could log on.

So what's the difference between that two methods? Or what extra steps need to take to make login possible?

Comment: It´s probably just a typo, so... /ad should be /add, and if you want to add a domain user, you should use > net user XXX strong_password /add /domain I recommend reading this [link.](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/net-user-command.htm)

Comment: @JannisAlexakis it's not a typo, /ad is an alias

Answer (score 0):

I believe UAC is blocking this. Try running the command prompt from administrator by right clicking on Command Prompt -> Run As Administrator. I just tried the command on my PC and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your command should work fine - it's the recognised way of creating LOCAL users.  When you attempt to logon, can you ensure you're trying to logon to the local account, and aren't specifying the domain?

Also, can you post the exact response you are getting when creating the user and when failing to logon?

One way to test the account is to use **runas**, e.g.:

```
runas /user:%COMPUTERNAME%\<ACCOUNT-NAME> cmd.exe
```